Which philosopher developed the theoretical foundation of physicalism?

Many contemporary philosophers claim to be ‘physicalists’; many of
these philosophers take themselves to be heirs to Greek atomism and
seventeenth century materialism. Many other contemporary philosophers
hold that ‘physicalism’ either admits of no intelligible formulation,
or else is hopelessly vulgar and undeserving of serious philosophical
attention. Before we can arbitrate this apparent dispute, we need to
get clearer about what ‘physicalism’ might mean. In the circumstances,
it would not be surprising to learn that those who claim to be
‘physicalists’ defend a far more modest doctrine than those
‘physicalist’ views which others allege to be hopelessly vulgar and
undeserving of serious philosophical attention.
https://philarchive.org/archive/OPPP-2

If people believe in it, then should there be some theoretical foundation for this branch of philosophy?

NOTE: According to the 2020 PhilPapers Survey, 51.93% of philosophers are physicalists.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Notwithstanding the fact that my views are hopelessly vulgar and undeserving of serious philosophical attention, I would argue that any adequate textbook of Physics could be used as a theoretical foundation and then leave it as an exercise for the reader to conclude that Physicalism must be true.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The SEP says "The word ‘materialism’ appears in English towards the end of the 17th century, but the word ‘physicalism’ was introduced into philosophy only in the 1930s by Otto Neurath (1931) and Rudolf Carnap (1959/1932), both of whom were key members of the Vienna Circle [...]"
As to whether that is the meaning that is being cited, I will let others judge...  But this is from their section on physicalism.
One can argue about whether being first to use the term makes one the "theoretical founder" or just first to give a name to an already existing approach. I suspect it was the latter, and that the actual roots go back as far as non-physicalism does. We can't cite who originated that approach either, and both were probably invented multiple times.
Hey, maybe I can describe myself as a dielectric materialist! I would get a charge out of that.

Unless you can be polarized by electric fields, you're more likely to be a dialectical materialist.

@gs; I've dealt with circuits where human capacitance was an issue... Yeah, the pun was stretching the point.

@keshlam - Expect some resistance from the spiritualists... (I first learned the word "spiritualists", as a teen, from one of Conan Doyle's stories. For a while I thought it referred to people who were addicted to alcoholic spirits... I've never been able to completely shake off that first misinterpretation...)
